# PyQt5 - Cerrar ventanas secundarias cuando la principal se cierre

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmainwindow

Tengo una pequeña aplicación la cual solo me falta corregir este error que sucede cuando llamo a la función y abre correctamente la ventana pero al cerrar la ventana `Win=MainApp()` se sigue manteniendo active y me quisiera que cuando la ventana principal sea cerrada esta también lo hiciera.

Estoy usando `QMainWindow` para la ventana principal y `QWidget` para la secundaria.

```
###Clase principal y Líneas de código###

def Read(self):
    self.w = OtraVentana()
    self.w.show()

##Clase de la Otra ventana###

Root=QApplication([])
Win=MainApp()
Win.show()
Root.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una solución al problema al fin.

Encontré un tutorial sobre los evento de `QMainWindow` y apareció el evento `closeEvent` el cual puedes establecer una función y asignarle que cuando al `QMainWindow` se cierre, cierre consecutivamente la ventana secundaria.

```
def Read(self):
    self.w = OtraVentana()
    self.w.show()
   
def closeEvent(self, event):
    try:
        self.w.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Información para ayudar a quien sea :)